# How to describe the primes not dividing any Fermat number?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, divisibility, fermat-numbers

It was only last week that I noticed the awesome proof for the infinity of primes, inferred by the Fermat numbers $F_m=2^{2^m} +1,\,m=0,1,2,3,\ldots\:$ being pairwise coprime$-$a book proof indeed!

Fermat numbers satisfy the recursion
$F_{m+1}=\prod\limits_{k=0}^m F_k+2$, yielding directly their coprime property.

My initial question was if every odd prime appears as a divisor of some Fermat number?!
After some enquiry I found Édouard Lucas' Theorem saying that a prime divisor $p$ of $F_m$ where $m\geqslant 2$ has the form $\,p=2^{m+2}k+1\,$ for some $k$, or equivalently $\,2^{m+2}\mid (p-1)\,$. This excludes primes
$p\equiv 3\pmod 4$, with the exception $3=F_0$.

Thus focusing on prime divisors $p\equiv 1\pmod 4$ lets me ask for a more concise description:

> Can one characterise in a (preferably) uniform way all those primes $\equiv 1\pmod 4\,$ which do not divide any Fermat number?

The comments received until now hint at "No" as answer, or more reservedly, that this is not known.

Comment: I think that a simple criterion for this would quickly settle the question of which Fermat numbers were prime.  If I am right about that, then it is an open problem.

Comment: @lulu I just learned Lucas' thm, whence really not sure about this. If it can be made precise, then it would merit to be an answer.

Comment: I think you might be responding to my (now deleted) comment, which was inaccurate.  Without thinking too hard, I thought that Lucas' criterion worked both ways, which it clearly does not.  For instance $F_3=257$ is prime and $p=2^4\times 1 +1=17$ does not divide it.  That's why I revised my thinking to suggest that a simple test of the form you want would settle the primality of the Fermat numbers.  But of course I could be wrong yet again.

Comment: any prime that is 3 mod 4 will have $m=0$ working backwards.  That's 1 class of them.

Comment: The big search for fermat factors shows that there is no such characterization, but for any given prime, you can easily check whether it divides some fermat number because there is an upper bound for the exponent. A "random" prime is extremely likely to divide no fermat number. The known factors are summarized here : http://www.prothsearch.com/fermat.html

Comment: @Peter   I edited the question. Would you like to forge your comment into an answer? That would be welcome!

Comment: If the odd prime $p$ is less than $2^{m+2}$ then $2^{n+2}\not |\, (p-1)$ for any $n\ge m,$ so  $p | F_n \implies n\le m+1.$ For example $p=13$ and $m=2$... $13$ does not divide any of $F_0, F_1, F_2, F_3.$ So $13$ does not divide any $ F_n.$

Comment: An improvement on my prior comment is that if $p$ is prime and $p-1=2^AK$ where $K$ is odd and $A\ge 2$ then $ p \not |\,F_n$ for any $n\ge A-1$.

Comment: Eisenstein, a contemporary of Gauss, conjectured that $1+2^{2^{2^n}}$ ( i.e. $1+2^{(-1+F_n)}\;$ ) is always prime. I dk whether it is known that $1+2^{256}$  is prime or not.